# Can't left click on TextBox in a ListBox (With drag and drop) WPF

Tags: wpf, textbox, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have a ListBox that contains a TextBox (And also picture and other thing).
The problem is I can't left click in the TextBox because of the previewmouseleftbuttondown which i handle for the ListBox.
It means that the program handle my left click with this function and thats why I can't write in the textBox.
What can i do about it?

The listBox:

```
ListBox x:Name="lbTwo" Grid.Column="2 " Margin="{StaticResource SplitRight}"
                 Drop="ListBox_Drop" AllowDrop="True"
                 PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" MouseDown="someListBox_MouseDown"
                 Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=styleLightListBox}"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
```

The items it contains:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="templateLightListBoxItem">
        <Grid Margin="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Number_pic}"
                       Stretch="Fill"
                       Height="40"
                       Width="40"></Image>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
            <Grid 
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label x:Name="label" Content="Your number: " Grid.Column="0" />
                <TextBox x:Name="NumberTextBox" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=mainNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Width="20"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Edit:

```
private void ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox destLisBox = (ListBox)sender;
            dragSource = destLisBox;

            GiveFeedbackEventHandler handler = new GiveFeedbackEventHandler(DragSource_GiveFeedback);

            this.dragSource.GiveFeedback += handler;


            object data = GetDataFromListBox(dragSource, e.GetPosition(destLisBox));

            if (data != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(destLisBox, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }

private void DragSource_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //This loads the cursor from a stream ..
        if (_allOpsCursor == null)
        {
            {
                _allOpsCursor = new Cursor(path+@"\Icons\Red_Gear.cur");
            }
        }
        Mouse.SetCursor(_allOpsCursor);
        e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    finally { }
}
```

Comment: Are you marking the event as handled in your PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event handler? I don't think the fact that you have a handler for it will prevent the click from going through as long as you didn't set e.Handled = true;

Comment: @Rowbear No i don't... But when I'm deleting the handler from the Xaml - It works.
Edit: Actually i saw I'm calling a function that do it, but when i remove this line (e.Handled = true) or even delete the calling to this function - It still the same.

Comment: there must be some other code behind you're not presenting here then. I double checked by creating a ListBox like yours with an ItemTemplate like yours with the exact same event handlers you have (PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, MouseDown, PreviewTextInput), and the only way I can get the click not to go through to the TextBox is if I have e.Handled = true in the previewmouseleftbuttondown event. If you create an empty application stripping out extraneous code, I'm sure you'll find the same.

Comment: Hey, I have added a code.. As i said there is one place where you can see e.Handled = true, but moving this line isn't fixing the problem. @Rowbear

Comment: I don't have time to test right now, but the fact that you're doing a dragdrop in your mouse down handler is pretty key. You should initiate dragdrop on PreviewMouseMove instead.

Comment: Thanks, well for now i found a stupid solution so i cancel the drag and drop if the user press on the textBox...